# Gnome 3.14: Changing window icons to the left

Tags: gnome, 15.04

How may I move window icons to the left in Gnome 3.14 under Ubuntu 15.04? This question has been asked before, but considerably older versions of Ubuntu and Gnome.

Comment: They are already there. I don't want to bring 'em back.

Comment: Read my answer and you would see, that there is described how you can move the icons at the left side and so on.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In a terminal:

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout 'close,minimize,maximize:'

$ gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings overrides "{'Gtk/DecorationLayout':<'close,minimize,maximize:'>}"
```

Comment: The second line is what did the trick for me. Using gnome-tweaks i could set the window icons to the left for most apps, but not the gnome ones.