# Why Are My Window Buttons Not Moving to the Left?

Tags: gnome, gnome-tweak-tool

For some reason my windows border buttons will not move to the left when I tell it to with the Gnome Tweaks app. Well actually it does do it partly, the effect changes with some apps such as Firefox, Gimp, Inkscape, etc but not with the Gnome apps or Nautilus. It was working before. Does anyone have any recommendations on how to fix this?

[image: Screenshot 1]

Comment: Have you tried rebooting after making the change?

Comment: Yes I have, I had no luck.

Comment: What is the output of `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout` in Terminal?

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution [in this Ask Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/656084/gnome-3-14-changing-window-icons-to-the-left):

For me, changing the setting with gnome-tweaks correctly changed `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout` but nautilus and other gnome apps weren't affected.

I then did

```
gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings overrides
```

(gotten from that other question / answer) and sure enough it showed

```
('Gtk/ShellShowsAppMenu': <0>, 'Gtk/DecorationLayout': <'menu:minimize,maximize,close'>}
```

I then changed it to:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings overrides "{'Gtk/ShellShowsAppMenu': <0>, 'Gtk/DecorationLayout': <'close,minimize,maximize,menu:'>}"
```

and now it works as I want it to.

Comment: When you install Budgie it breaks the setting for Tweaks as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. I had installed the Budgie desktop just to try it out, but it broke my button customisation. This setting restored the previous button configuration.

Comment: After uninstalling Budgie and using "Tweaks" to move the buttons back to the right side, I wondered why certain applications (e.g. Firefox) still had the buttons on the left side. Reversing the command used here had the desired effect and moved the buttons back to the right side.